# Echo protected value of object in php

Tags: php, json, class, object, echo

This is an object printed in php using print_r.
I need to echo the id rp_1045AF4nxn0D3ubjmXBDZRSX given in the image below.

[image]

Comment: You should copy-paste your code. Since you have attached a screenshot, people who wish to respond would not be able to copy-paste code from your question.

Comment: I tried copy paste. But not displaying in proper format. I think this pic will be easy to understand the structure.

Comment: Yes, it won't display in the proper format. You should format your code  as "code" by clicking the `{ }` icon above the text editor

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) (Available in PHP 5+).

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("Stripe_Recipient");
$property = $class->getProperty("_apiKey");
$property->setAccessible(true);

echo $property->getValue($yourObject);
```

$yourObject should be the instance of the class you are trying to get the property from.

See [ReflectionProperty::setAccessible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php):

> Sets a property to be accessible. For example, it may allow protected and private properties to be accessed.

Full Example:

```
<?php

class MyTest {
    private $foo = 'bar';
}

$obj = new MyTest();

$class = new ReflectionClass("MyTest");
$property = $class->getProperty("foo");
$property->setAccessible(true);

echo $property->getValue($obj); // Prints 'bar'
```

Comment: But i dont want to risk the security.

Comment: You aren't, this is server side code. This just makes the property accessible to other areas of your PHP codebase. If someone has access to the PHP code then you have no security anyway.

Comment: I tried. Still the property doesnt change on printing.

Comment: @mirzavu I misread the docs. I've updated my example to show you how to do it.